# Laravel Multi-tenancy App MySQL Database Design

Tags: mysql, multi-tenant

I am building multi-tenancy app using Laravel and MySQL.

I am designing DB structure and I got confused.

I am going to design as following but maybe I am wrong.

Related tables are `websites`, `domains`, `custom_domains`.

```
websites table:
id
user_id
domain

domains table:
id
user_id
website_id
name
... // domain registration related fields.

custom_domains table:
id
user_id
website_id
name
type
```

`websites` table's domain field can be either `domains` table's name or `custom_domains` table's name.

`domains` table is for the purchased domains in our website.
`custom_domains` table is for either **subdomain** of our main domain or **pointed domains**.

When customers hit domain name, if that domain pointed to our server, then it will check `websites` table first.

Users will be able to change primary domain (once it is in websites table, I will set it as primary domain).

Can anyone please help me with better DB design?

Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with the current design?

Comment: Thanks, I think there will be better way.
I am quite new in database design so I don't know this is good way or not.

Comment: The good database design allows you to answer all the questions (queries) you need to ask from the database. Do you have any questions (queries) you cannot get an answer to with your db design?